# cv2.HoughCircles takes more than 15 minutes to run

Tags: python-3.x, hough-transform

This code took 19 minutes to execute. I ran this code on [this](https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/RAGZOcxKRBCnABp1E0Ae) image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('D:\\hough\\coins.jpg',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                            param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

cv2.imwrite('detected circles.jpg', cimg)
cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I want something like [this](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html) and this is the output that i received:
[image]

How can this be fixed?